# Received comma while excluding letter using reqex

Tags: javascript

How can I exclude letters from input `rpn("2 3 + 7  d -");` ?

I've tried with this:

```
function rpn(input) {

    var str = input.split(/[a-z]/);
    return arr;
};
```

but then I receive `2 3 + 7 , -`, so comma instead of `d`
I then tried to remove spaces with `var str = input.split(/[a-z]\s+/);`, but this didn't work at all.

I'm looking for a result like that: `2,3,+,7,-`, so I can push it to an array and work with it there.

Comment: `/[a-z]\s+/` matches any letter from a-z followed by one or more spaces.

Comment: Use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to extract numbers as array

Comment: The comma is from the _Array_ being converted to a _String_. What you call `str` is actually an _Array_. You probably didn't want to `split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not clear...

If you want to split your string case of letter OR space you can do something like this :

```
"2 3 + 7  d -".split( /[a-z ]+/ );
                           ^
                         space is here
```

Will return an array of strings

```
[ '2', '3', '+', '7', '-' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Its unclear what you are trying to do, from what I understand you want to strip all letters and spaces from your string in which case this should work:

```
function rpn(input) {
    var str = input.replace(/[a-zA-Z]\s+/g,'');
    return str;
};
```

However as mentioned in your last sence you want to return it as an array seperated by spaces in which case this would work:

```
function rpn(input) {
    var str = input.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'').split(' ');
    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be converting the `str` which is actually actually an `Array`. Instead use `RegExp.match` with `[^a-z ]` and concat with an empty string which will internally call `Array.join(",")`

```
function rpn(input){
   return input.match(/[^a-z ]/g) + ""; 
  // don't concat if you want an array instead of string
}
```

Comment: I don't know... but your tip is smart –> up!